# Counting frequency of words from predefined dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nltk, text-processing

I am performing text analysis for a document using mostly Pandas, NLTK, and TextBlob. I want to obtain the frequencies of only predefined terms. The rows in the document are reviews, and there is a predefined list of associations between words that constitutes a good or a bad review. Good reviews are likely to have (easy-->use), (service-->good) while bad reviews are likely to have (fee-->lower), (easier-->make).

What I would like to do is use these associations to classify reviews as good or bad based on if, for example, text in a particular row has "easy" and "use" closely associated, or "service" and "good". What I am stuck on is the structure--how do I come up with a "good" and "bad" dictionary of tuples and use this with maybe n-grams or something to derive an association?

Comment: Worry about the structure at the end. For a start, just work with two lists. One containing good associations as tuples, other containing bad. A bigger challenge for you is settling on the "logic" of the problem. How do you weigh multiple matches in same sentence? Word distance? Cleaned word distance? some vector notation? Tackle those problems as you see them. What if you have matches in both good and bad with same distances?

Comment: So, you're asking how to store the knowledge that some tuple are "good" and some are "bad"?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Thanks for the response! A few questions: what do you mean by cleaned word distance? How about vector notation? using TextBlob().ngrams(2) gives you bigrams of a certain data structure, do you mean matching that data structure to my list?

Comment: @Acccumulation Essentially that's one of my questions, yeah

Comment: I myself do not know the appropriate way to go about choosing a metric for measuring goodness or badness. The "cleaned" word distance however refers, in my mind atleast, to remove stopwords first from the sentences before comparing for distances for association. @S420L

Comment: Perhaps you should try Naive Bayes or other classical methods before inventing something from scratch?